# Get element with its ancestor in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML like this:

```
...
<suite @name="SameName">   
... lot of tags
       <msg level="FAIL"></msg>
```

My XPath is

```
//msg[contains(@level,'FAIL')]
```

it returns the `<msg>` node. Could I also get name of suite in one XPath expression?

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath expression

```
//suite[.//msg/@level='FAIL']/@name
```

to select the `@name` of the `suite` element that has a descendant `msg` element with a `@level` attribute value equal to `'FAIL'`.